# How to Visual c++ like javascript date?

Tags: javascript, c++, date

Visual c++ like Javascrit (new Date()).getTime() function?
Function return (1475262776012) milliseconds.

Comment: Can you describe more plz?

Comment: Need Javascript (new Date()).getTime() function in Visual c++

Comment: I see you're new in SO it's better to know how to ask questions [READ THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) Otherwise people give you Negative reputations and it prevents you to ask more

Comment: Looks like a unix timestamp you have there, hoss. [Use std::time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time)

Comment: Also C++ unix timestamp return length 10. javascript also is 13. Why? Thanks.

Comment: Just doing a bit of reading and have to reverse myself. The milliseconds gets in the way. That's the extra three characters because time returns unix time in seconds. Back in a minute with a less trivial solution based on `chrono`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to w3schools, and other more credible sources, getTime returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. Basic C and C++ timekeeping, `time_t` operates in seconds.

The Modern C++ approach is to take advantage of the [`chrono` library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono; // just to shorten the namespacing

    //get the current time in highest possible precision
    auto cur_time = high_resolution_clock::now();

    //get the distance between now and the start of unix time 
    auto unixtime = cur_time.time_since_epoch();

    // convert to milliseconds
    auto unixtime_in_ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(unixtime);

    // convert to a number and output
    std::cout << unixtime_in_ms.count();
}
```

If you want to, most of that can be shortened into this ugly one-liner:

```
auto unixtime_in_ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
```

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools, the site is full of errors. Use ECMA-262 for normative references (e.g. [*Date.prototype.getTime*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.gettime)) or [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) where examples and further explanation is suitable.

Comment: @RobG Man, you can't trust nuthin' no more. Thanks though. Will keep that in mind. I take it the ECMA link is pretty much the standard document in HTML form?

Comment: The ECMA link is **the** language standard for ECMAScript. ;-)

Comment: Makes sense. Wouldn't be seemly to find it in something static like a PDF.

Comment: It's available on the [*ECMA International*](http://www.ecma-international.org) web site is [*PDF or HTML*](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).